# Does CSS style cascade down from one html5 page to another?

Tags: php, html, css

I'm quite new to HTML & CSS but currently facing a bit of a problem. I've two pages (one html5, one php), say page1.html and page2.php. Both pages have a jquery js and two css files(one for jquery, one for jquery mobile) attached to them. There is a hyper-link that can be used to navigate from page1 to page2. page2.php generates a table using data retrieved from a MYSQL table.

If page2 is loaded into a browser directly, it displays quite well and all the styles are applied as expected. However, all hell breaks loose, if page2 is navigated to from page1. In that instance, the table appear to loose all the styles and is not displayed correctly. As a matter of fact, looks quite horrible.

My thinking is that the two pages are independent of each other. Is it possible for some style settings in page1 to be responsible for this baffling situation. This is really driving me nuts.

By the way- I'm using Dreamweaver 6 as the IDE.

Comment: http is stateless, each page call is unique, there is no hang over from any prevous page

Comment: Any possible way you can either upload the pages so they can be seen live, or at least post the code from both?

Comment: You should check the link from the html to php page. It should be the same link like you type into your browser. Could you post the link you type into your browser versus the link that is in your html page ?

Comment: Page1.html (index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I found out that by simply moving the style link statements (shown below) in page2.php to just before the **BODY** closing tag, the problem disappears.

```
<link href="table.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="jquery.mobile-1.0b3/jquery.mobile-1.0b3.min.css"   rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.0b3/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="jquery.mobile-1.0b3/jquery.mobile-1.0b3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="styles/f.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Can't understand why this is so but just too happy to get over this.